# VLC 2.2.4 - how to turn on the option "pause on left mouse click"?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want the option in VLC to pause a video when I click the left button of the mouse.
I've found a solution here: https://github.com/nurupo/vlc-pause-click-plugin/tree/master/vlc-2.2.x%2B
However, the option  Video -> Filters -> Pause/Play video on mouse click doesn't appear. I moved the file to C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\video_filter

But I can't turn this option on. It doesn't appear on the list. Could you tell me how to install it? I'm using the latest stable version of VLC. BTW I was trying with the 32bit and 64bit version of the plugin and it doesn't appear on the list under advanced video settings.

Comment: There is a plugin here for it: https://github.com/nurupo/vlc-pause-click-plugin Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/172494/play-pause-vlc-with-mouse-click

Comment: You didn't read my question properly. Your link is practically the same. I've installed this plugin but I can't turn it on because it doesn't appear on the list. I don't want other solutions/workarounds because I'm asking specifically about this plugin. It's not a duplicate question!

Comment: opps, you are right about the plugin, but the duplicatye is real, there is a similar question there: superuser.com/questions/172494/play-pause-vlc-with-mouse-click

Comment: I just want this plugin to work. How to do it?

Comment: Well, I`ve tried to install the plugin but I failed, I`ll try again in 1-2 hours.

Comment: I faced the same problem. My VLC was 32-bit and my OS was 64-bit so I mistakenly downloaded 64-bit "vlc pause click plugin" and much time was wasted. Please make sure, if your VLC is 32-bit, then you are not mistakenly using 64-bit plugin and vice versa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play/pause VLC with mouse click](https://superuser.com/questions/172494/play-pause-vlc-with-mouse-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to get the thing work. My solution is to install VLC 32-bit version with 32-bit plugin and all magically appears. If you have Windows 10 I recommend installing the 32-bit version. Other combinations didn't work in my case. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: In Windows10, VLC 3.0.8 - 64bit works fine with the 64bit  3.0 plugin, the same in Linux. On a Mac I made it work with VLC 3.0.0, still 64bit. In your case it might have been some problem for the specific 2.2.4 version. I couldn't make this work on a Mac with the VLC 2.2.2, 64bit version (which I wanted for different reasons).

Answer (score 13):

Okay I succeeded a installation of the plugin.
It's working for me, it wasn't easy I guess I didn't have the right files at first.
Sorry if you can't understand french.

First this I used 2.2.4

[image]

I downloaded the 64bit version (even if my vlc is 32 bits, my os is 64)
You can see here:[image]

You extract the dll in the folder: C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\video_filter
[image]

Then in the settings you follow the instructions:

[image]

I've set it up to middle mouse button, It's more handy, left is for full screen, right is for small menu so.
[image]

```
Restart VLC to load the newly added plugin
Go into advanced preferences: Tools -> Preferences -> Show settings -> All
Enable/Disable the plugin with a checkbox: (in advanced preferences) Video -> Filters -> Pause/Play video on mouse click
Enable/Disable the plugin with a checkbox: (in advanced preferences) Interface -> Control Interfaces -> Pause/Play video on mouse click
Change mouse button to the one you want: (in advanced preferences) Video -> Filters -> Pause click -> Mouse Button
Restart VLC for settings to take place
Play a video
Click on video picture to pause/play the video
```

Comment: The problem is I'm doing the same all the time but, I don't have this option on the list. Take a look. I've even changed the interface to French.

VLC - screenshot
http://i.stack.imgur.com/REvQl.jpg

Comment: It`s seems that you may don`t have the right dll at the righ place or the right vesion of vlc. What have you downloaded? It`s suppose to be a single dll file. (I`ll be back 27 june 2016, I wish you solve the problem.)

Comment: Hmmm. Which version of Windows do you have? I've just tried on Windows 7 and everything worked really well. But on Windows 10 it still isn't working. Thank you for you time and for the help.

Comment: I'm running on win10

Comment: if 64 bit version doesn't work - try 32 bit and vice versa. Win7x64, plugin 64 didn't appear in the list, whilst plugin 32 appeared. The problem: it does not work anyway, no effect either left or middle click :(

Comment: You need to put the correct 32/64 bit dll in the correct version depending on which version of VLC you have installed, If you have a 64 bit OS then install the 64 bit version of VLC and the 64 bit version of the dll.  Once copied to the correct location the instructions above work! - they did for me - Thanks Mark! >>>> 64bit: C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\video_filter  for 32bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\video_filter

Answer (score 3):

don't forget to go to "advanced preferences" -> "interface" -> "control interfaces" and check the "Pause/play video on mouse click" button

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the dll installed and pause on click to work.  Luckily I'm an old school 20+ year developer otherwise I'd of been lost.  The main trick that finally work to make the check box show up was using the 2.2 version 32 bit, tried 64 bit first since my system is 64 bit.  Anyway, thanks to the dynamic link library author and sharing.  Happy now!